# show action does not work on key press but works on click function

Tags: jquery

I've searched but could not find an explanation to my issue.

I have a menu with three items which all have submenus with three items each. I want to open the submenu for the active menu item with key press.

I'm able to achieve this with `$(this).parent().find('.submenu').show();` on click function but it does not work on keydown function. If i do `$('.submenu').show();` for the corresponding key, it works, but all the submenus displays. So if anyone could explain what I don't understand and what I should do to make only the current submenu display on key press, I would be very grateful!

This is the function for the keys:

```
switch(e.keyCode)
    {       
        // left key 
        case arrow.left:

        break;

        // up key
        case arrow.up: //this works
            $('a:focus').closest('li').prev().find('a.option').focus();
        break;

        // right key
        case arrow.right:
            $('.submenu').show(); //this works but shows all the submenus
        break;

        // down key
        case arrow.down: //this works
            $('a:focus').closest('li').next().find('a.option').focus();
        break;
    }
```

And this is the click function which works:

```
$('a').click(function() {

    this.focus();

    $(this).parent().find('.submenu').show(); 

});
```

Here's a fiddle with my code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npcasrk1/4/)

Comment: Could you add the code for your event handler.

Comment: Add your markup please. And jsfiddle will be good if its possitble.

Comment: Where are you using `switch`?

Comment: @Petroff I've added a fiddle with my code...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/npcasrk1/5/ Well here the right arrow click work, but i have problem with up/down arrows events. They don't work before mouse click event. That `:focus` don't look so good. Better add some `temp class` and use it to select element. And validation for `if (not selected element) select first` will be good.

Comment: @Petroff Thank you! I tried something like that but could not get it to work. You mean like `addClass` and `removeClass`? Can I use the same technique to put focus on the first subitem when the submenu opens?

Comment: @jdo you can do it with `focus`, but its easy to lose focus without want it.

Answer (score 1):

In your switch you're telling it to show all the `.submenu` items while in your click you're narrowing it down to the `.submenu` related to the clicked item. You can use the same approach in you switch statement and only open the item which the related `a` element has focus:

```
case arrow.right:
    $('a:focus').parent().children('.submenu').show();
    //...
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npcasrk1/9/)

EDIT:

To change the focus to the submenu items, you just grab the first item in the just opened submenu and set the focus().

Since you've been adding the focus on `a` elements I kept it the same, but your sumbenues use a different structure (`.option` for `a` elements, but `.suboption` for `li` elements, etc )

```
// left key 
case arrow.left:
    //now you want to change the focus back on main menu item I presume?
    $('a:focus').closest('.submenu').hide().parent().children('a').focus();
    break;
//right key
case arrow.right:
    $('a:focus').parent().children('.submenu').show().find('a:first').focus();
    break;
```

[edited jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npcasrk1/10/)

Comment: I understand that, the thing that made me confused was that I could not get the code for the click action to work on the key press event...

Comment: Added the jsfiddle. Please check and let me know whether it's the desired  behavior. Isn't the code in click only opens/closes the related submenu?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, the click function works as I wanted, but I could not get it to work for key press. Any suggestion for how I can put focus on the first submenu item when the submenu opens?

Comment: Edited the answer. It probably would be better though if you have similar structure for your menu and submenu items (or alternatively handle them in separate functions).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
case arrow.right:
                $('a:focus').next().show();
```

also

```
// hide submenu on default
    $('ul li ul').hide();
    $(document).off();
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();


        // declare variable for submenu
        var menu = $('ul');
        var submenu = $('ul li ul');

        // declare variables for the keys
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
            arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40};



        switch(e.keyCode)
        {       
            // left key 
            case arrow.left:

            break;

            // up key
            case arrow.up: //this works
                $('a:focus').closest('li').prev().find('a.option').focus();

            break;

            // right key
            case arrow.right:
                $('a:focus').next().show(); //this works but shows all the submenus

            break;

            // down key
            case arrow.down: //this works
                $('a:focus').closest('li').next().find('a.option').focus();
            break;
        }
   console.log(123,$(':focus'));
    });

    $('a').click(function() {

        this.focus();

        $(this).parent().find('.submenu').toggle(); 

    });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mjvakili/npcasrk1/8/)